# Haskell Replace a value in a list with another value

Tags: haskell

I am pretty new to Haskell. I am trying to write a program that takes two values and a list and replaces every instance of the first value in the list with the second. E.g. `repOcc 'n' 'i' "pink"` would return `"piik"`.

The following is my code:

```
repOcc :: t -> t -> [t] -> [t]
repOcc x y (z:zs) = if z == x
                      then z = y
                      subst x y zs
                      else subst x y zs
```

The error I am receiving at compile time is:

```
rev.hs:3 :32: error: 
   parse error on input '='
   Perhaps you need a 'let' in a 'do' block?
   e.g. 'let x = 5' instead of 'x = 5'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Comment: Please indicate how the code deviates from your expectation. Is there a compiler error? What is that error? Does the program give incorrect output? What is an example of an input and incorrect output?

Comment: Start simpler: can you write a function `f from to x` that evaluates to `to` if `x` is equal to `from` and `x` unchanged otherwise?

Comment: On compilation, I am getting a parse error and the compiler is suggesting me to add 'let' in the 'do block'

Comment: @RNee please edit your question to include the exact text of the parse error.

Comment: @RNee And also the code the error points to. There is no do block in the function above, for instance.

Comment: Note that single quotes delimit a character whereas double quotes delimit a list of characters. I made this small correction for sake of clarity to other beginners with a similar question.

Comment: Not specific to Haskell but in every functional language you have a `map` function for this task. Such as `map (\c -> if c == 'n' then 'i' else c) "pink"
` will give you `"piik"`

Comment: A good first step into Haskell is forgetting that you ever heard of assignments.

Answer (score 5):

Your program looks rather "*imperative*" whereas Haskell aims to be more "*declarative*". So you can not set a variable `z` in a list: once a list is constructed, you can not alter it anymore. So you have to construct a new list where elements that are equal to `x` are set to `y`.

Next you make use of the `(==)` function. That function is defined in the `Eq` typeclass, so you need to add `Eq t` as a type constraint to the signature.

So now we can start to construct such function. Usually when working with a list, we make use of recursion. The base case of the recursion is usually the empty list. In case we encounter the empty list, we should return an empty list, regardless what `x` and `y` are. So we use underscores as "*don't care*" patterns, and use `[]` as the list pattern, and write:

```
repOcc _ _ [] = []
```

The recursive case is when the list contains a head `h` and a tail `t` in a `(h:t)` pattern. In that case we check whether `h` is equal to `x`. In case it is, we construct a list with `y` as head, otherwise `h` is still the head.

```
repOcc x y (h:t) | x == h = y : tl
                 | otherwise = h : tl
```

Now the question remains what the tail of the result list `tl` should be. Here we use recursion, so we call `repOcc` with `x y t`:

```
    where tl = repOcc x y t
```

Or putting it together:

```
repOcc :: Eq t => t -> t -> [t] -> [t]
repOcc _ _ [] = []
repOcc x y (h:t) | x == h = y : tl
                 | otherwise = h : tl
    where tl = repOcc x y t
```

We can write such recursive functions, but the above is actually a special case of a `map` function: we map every character in such way that we check whether it is equal to `x` and if it is, we return `y`, otherwise we return `h`. So we can rewrite the above as:

```
repOcc :: Eq t => t -> t -> [t] -> [t]
repOcc x y ls = map (\h -> if h == x then y else h) ls
```

We can further improve the code by making use of *eta*-reduction:

```
repOcc :: Eq t => t -> t -> [t] -> [t]
repOcc x y = map (\h -> if h == x then y else h)
```